# my .phtml file isnt showing

Tags: cms, magento-1.9

I have this line

```
<!-- HEADER EOF -->
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('slideshow'); ?>
```

in my header.phtml file however i need to move it so it is within the page. I thought about just pasting that line into its only .phtml file called slideshow.phtml then calling that on my CMS page using the line

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/html/slidershow.phtml"}}
```

as the template file is located in design/frontend/mytheme/default/template/page/html. and when i look on my page with the block hints on it says the block is there but is displaying nothing.

how can i get this to display my slideshow.phtml file

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the name on your block definition. You are calling `getChildHtml` which takes the block name but your definition needs to be updated to include a name:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="slideshow" template="page/html/slidershow.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Also note that, if the block type is not `core/template`, its not going to show up in frontend. That is because, there may be block specific calling inside `slider.phtml` . That will not render, if you use `core/template` as block type

Answer (score 3):

You can also call the page directly by using this code

```
<?php echo $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('page/html/slidershow.phtml')->toHtml();
```